# Python I want a different way of doing this while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, try-catch

I wrote this code for the same program but I want it to work the same way with out using the try and ValueError

```
total = 0.0
while True:
    try:
        total =+ float(raw_input("enter a number or quit to finish"))
    except ValueError:
        break
print total
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you really want that `=+` there? Was `+=` what you were looking for? Also, what is wrong with the `try-except`?

Comment: There's no good reason not to use `try-except` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just want to handle `"quit"` or a float, that's easy:

```
total = 0.0
while True:
    value = raw_input("enter a number or quit to finish"))
    if value == "quit":
        break
    total += float(value)
print total
```

But if the user types, say, `qiut` or `2..137`, the program will bail out with a `ValueError`. How do you protect against that, without a `try`?

Or, what if you want to prevent the user from entering, say, `inf` or `-inf` or `nan`, or something that will (at least on some platforms) overflow to one of those (e.g., try `1e309` on most systems)?

Well, you need some way to verify that the `float` call is going to work in advance.

First, you have to parse [Python 2.7's floating point literal syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals). At least you're not dealing with Python 3.x, where, e.g., `float('١٠٣')` is perfectly valid and means `103.0`. The language is easily translatable to a regular language, meaning `re` or plain string methods should be enough, or you can implement the grammar with something like [`PyParsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) or a hand-rolled recursive descent parser instead of translating.

Next, you need to evaluate the value to make sure it's not going to give an error when evaluated as a float. [`sys.float_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) should have all the information you need… except that Python 2.7 doesn't actually define what is and isn't an error. In general, overflow automatically turns into `inf` or `-inf`, and underflow to `0`, but you may need a bit of trial and error to see what it does for all the edge cases (or, alternatively, look over your interpreter's source code).

You can probably optimize this part by first ruling in and out everything that's clearly illegal/safe (e.g., if there's no exponent and the length is short enough, it can't possibly overflow), but there will be some range you will have to check in detail.

Or, while you're evaluating the number, you might as well skip the `float` anyway, and just use the number you evaluated. That even allows you to use *different* rules from Python 2.7 if you want (e.g., handle Persian numerals, or forms like `1.2x10^3` instead of just `1.2e3`, or allow thousands separators, or…).

I won't write the code for you, because this would all be an insane thing to do. It will take a lot of design, coding, testing, and debugging, and in the end it will run a few orders of magnitude slower than just letting Python `try` the `float` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the input in a variable, then in the `try` clause, convertion it into a `float`. If it the convert is successful, add it to `total`, if not, check if it is `'quit' to exit the program:

```
total = 0.0
while True:
    a = raw_input("Enter a number or quit to finish: ")
    try:
        total += float(a)
    except ValueError:
        if a == 'quit':
            break
print total
```

**Test:**

```
Enter a number or quit to finish: 2
Enter a number or quit to finish: 3
Enter a number or quit to finish: StackOverflow
Enter a number or quit to finish:  
Enter a number or quit to finish: 4
Enter a number or quit to finish: quit
9.0
```

**Note:** This code will handle the case when the user inputs a string that is different to `'quit'`.

Comment: The OP wants to do it without the `try-except`. :/

Comment: so in order to do something like this you have to do a try-ValueError every time??

Comment: To get the intended result, *in a relatively easy way*, yes.